Getting an error when using FullCalendar React library
I tried to implement a React calendar with local storage and the FullCalendar library using the below code.
<FullCalendar 
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]} 
    initialView="timeGridWeek"
    headerToolbar={{           
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    }}
    events={calendarEvents}
    editable={true}
    eventClick={handleEventClick}
/>

However, I'm getting the following error:
Error: 'FullCalendar' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'typeof FullCalendar' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type 'typeof FullCalendar' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) =\> Component\<any, any, any\>'.
Type 'FullCalendar' is missing the following properties from type 'Component\<any, any, any\>': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refs

The suggested posts just offer specific solutions but not the general approach to this issue.

Please also include the code of how you import the FullCalendar component.

Please [edit] the question to show the line in packages.json for this component.
